# RESTeasy + Server mock + ExceptionMapper not found

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a scenario where `ExceptionMapper` are used in JAX-RS using RESTeasy 2.0.1.GA . This works all fine.

I'd now like to test the whole thing using RESTeasy's [mock mechanism](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#RESTEasy_Server-side_Mock_Framework). Unfortunately my ExceptionMapper-provider is not registered. What am I missing?

```
POJOResourceFactory factory = new POJOResourceFactory(SomeWebResource.class);

Dispatcher dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
dispatcher.getRegistry().addResourceFactory(factory); 

MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.get("url");
MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();

// here my exception is thrown
dispatcher.invoke(request, response);

// but I expect the response to be 404 (which works outside the mock setup)
Assert.assertEquals(response.getStatus(), 404);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution. Needed to register the ExceptionMapper manually:

```
dispatcher.getProviderFactory().addExceptionMapper(SomeExceptionMapper.class);
```

Comment: Note: addExceptionMapper()'s visibility was changed to protected in later versions. dispatcher.getProviderFactory().registerProvider(SomeExceptionMapper.class) works instead.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this problem for a few days now, I think it's worth mentioning what @Joe W wrote in the comment of the above answer as it's own answer:

"Note: `addExceptionMapper()`'s visibility was changed to protected in later versions. `dispatcher.getProviderFactory().registerProvider(SomeExceptionMapper.class)` works instead."